# How to check if a number < 1 is power of 2?

Tags: java, algorithm, math

for example:
0.5 and 0.25 is power of 2 but 0.3 is not, also I know checking if integer is power of 2 is easy, but how to find if number is power of 2 if the number < 1?

```
public bool isPowerOf2(float number){
    if(number>1){
        //easy to write
    }else if(number==1){
        return true;
    }else{
        //hard to write
    }
}
```

Comment: isPowerOf2(1/x) = isPowerOf2(x). However I doubt that the number > 1 case is "easy to write" in a useful manner

Comment: @Aakash How's it unclear? "It's easy to check if an integer is a power of two; how do I do it with non-integers?"

Comment: You can write them the same way for all numbers except denormals, but that's probably using a different trick than you had in mind

Comment: What's your algorithm to test large numbers? It might give you an idea for small numbers.

Comment: For example, the algorithm for large numbers "Keep dividing by two, see if you hit 1 (or go below)" suggests an algorithm for small numbers "Keep *multiplying* by two, see if you hit 1 (or go above)"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this solution:

```
public boolean isPowerOf2(float number){
    if(number>1){
        //easy to write
    }else if(number==1){
        return true;
    }else if(number>0){
        return isPowerOf2(1.0f/number);
    }else
        return false;
}
```

By the way you can solve this simply by checking the bits of float binary representation:

```
public static boolean isPowerOfTwo(float i) {
    int bits = Float.floatToIntBits(i);
    if((bits & ((1 << 23)-1)) != 0)
        return ((bits & (bits-1)) == 0); // denormalized number
    int power = bits >>> 23;
    return power > 0 && power < 255; // 255 = Infinity; higher values = negative numbers
}
```

Comment: If you mean bits solution, then it's already checked: `power` includes sign and will be more than 255 for negative numbers (`255` = `Infinity`).

Comment: @TagirValeev Could you indicate (in the answer) if rounding errors could influence the answer of either solution?

Comment: @MaartenBodewes, as powers of two have finite representation in binary, it seems difficult for me to provide an example when rounding error could influence the answer. If you can provide a good example, I will include it into the answer.

Comment: I might try and find something programmatically or logically...later.

Answer (score 3):

Though using 1/x will likely work fine, one might be worried about roundoff errors.

Use [`Float.floatToRawIntBits(float).`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html#floatToRawIntBits(float))  You *probably* want to check that bit 22 is on but bits 21-0 are off (also the sign bit should be 0). This works for both positive and negative powers of 2.  The actual power is in bits 30-23.

Addendum: if bit 21 is off, but exactly one of bits 20-0 are on, it is a power of 2, as mentioned by @anonymous.  There is a well know trick to quickly test if exactly one bit is set, which you can surely find somewhere on Stack Overflow.

Comment: A number can also be a power of 2 if number is positive, the (biased) exponent is zero and there's exactly one bit set in the mantissa.

Comment: You should also care about denormalized numbers.

Comment: I know there are some gory details - thanks for the reminders!

Comment: It's nice to post answers even late at night, but I see a lot of maybe's. As for the "well known trick": what about [`bitCount`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#bitCount-int-)?

Answer (score 0):

Just call `isPowerOf2(1.0/number);` in `else` block. It should resolve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Java uses IEEE 754 to encode floats. The portion from bits 22 to 0 in the binary encoding represent the mantissa (m). If m has exactly one 1 then the float is a power of 2.

http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/91float/

```
(-1)^s × m × 2^(e - 127)
```

Sign bit (s) (bit 31). The most significant bit represents the sign of the number (1 for negative, 0 for positive).

Exponent field (e) (bits 30 - 23). The next 8 bits represent the exponent. By convention the exponent is biased by 127. This means that to represent the binary exponent 5, we encode 127 + 5 = 132 in binary (10000100). To represent the binary exponent -5 we encode 127 - 5 = 122 in binary (01111010). This convention is alternative to two's complement notation for representing negative integers.

Mantissa (m) (bits 22 - 0). The remaining 23 bits represent the mantissa, normalized to be between 0.5 and 1. This normalization is always possible by adjusting the binary exponent accordingly. Binary fractions work like decimal fractions: 0.1101 represents 1/2 + 1/4 + 1/16 = 13/16 = 0.8125. Not every decimal number can be represented as a binary fraction. For example 1/10 = 1/16 + 1/32 + 1/256 + 1/512 + 1/4096 + 1/8192 + ... In this case, the number 0.1 is approximated by the closest 23 bit binary fraction 0.000110011001100110011... One further optimization is employed. Since the mantissa always begins with a 1, there is no need to explicitly store this hidden bit.